# Effect of single hash in object-like macro

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, language-lawyer

Is `#` permitted in an object-like macro, and if so, what happens?

The **C** standard only defines the behaviour of `#` in a macro for function-like macros.

Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define A X#Y
#define B(X) #X
#define C(X) B(X)

int main()
{
    printf(C(A) "\n");
}
```

gcc outputs `X#Y`, suggesting that it permits `#` to be present and performs no special processing. However, since the definition of the `#` operator does not define the behaviour in this case, is it actually undefined behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

As you noticed, `#` only has a defined effect in function-like macros. *§ 6.10.3.2/1* (all references to the standard are to the C11 draft ([N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf))). To see what happens in object-like macros, we must look elsewhere.

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> ```
> # define identifier replacement-list new-line
> ```
>
> defines an
>   object-like macro
>   that causes each subsequent instance of the macro name
>   to be replaced by the replacement list of preprocessing tokens that constitute the
>   remainder of the directive. [...]

*§ 6.10.3/9*

Therefore, the only question is whether `#` is allowed in a `replacement-list`. If so, it takes part in replacement as usual.

We find the syntax in *§ 6.10/1*:

```
replacement-list:
    pp-tokens (opt.)

pp-tokens:
    preprocessing-token
    pp-tokens preprocessing-token
```

Now, is `#` a valid `preprocessing-token`? *§ 6.4/1* says:

```
preprocessing-token:
    header-name
    identifier
    pp-number
    character-constant
    string-literal
    punctuator
    each non-white-space character that cannot be one of the above
```

It's certainly not a `header-name` (*§ 6.4.7/1*), it's not allowed in `identifier` tokens (*§ 6.4.2.1/1*), nor is it a `pp-number` (which is basically any number in an allowed format, *§ 6.4.8/1*), nor a `character-constant` (such as `u'c'`, *§ 6.4.4.4/1*) or a `string-literal` (exactly what you'd expect, e.g. `L"String"`, *§ 6.4.5/1*).

However, it is listed as a `punctuator` in *§ 6.4.6/1*. Therefore, it is allowed in the `replacement-list` of an object-like macro and will be copied verbatim. It is now subject to rescanning as described in *§ 6.10.3.4*. Let us look at your example:

`C(A)` will be replaced with `C(X#Y)`. `#` has no special effect here, because it is not in the `replacement-list` of `C`, but its argument. `C(X#Y)` is obviously turned into `B(X#Y)`. Then `B`'s argument is turned into a string literal via the `#` operator in `B`'s `replacement-list`, yielding `"X#Y"`

Therefore, you don't have undefined behavior.